# Why is mapbox map so slow when you add 3000 or more amount of markers?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

When I add 3000 or more markers to Mapbox map, sometimes it stops working, or sometimes it is very slow. What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The right solution is to use a `symbol` layer instead. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol